# Android: Smooth DrawerLayout animations on Fragment Change

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, animation

I'm working on an Android app that uses a navigation drawer and multiple navigation menu items. Inflating the views and running onCreate() takes some time, which makes the drawer close animation very laggy. I'm already working on optimizing the fragment layout itself to reduce jank, but the animation is still laggy.

My quick fix was adding a drawer listener and calling getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(...).commit() on drawer close. However the problem with this is that the previous fragment still remains in the UI for a few milliseconds after the drawer is closed, which looks arguably worse than with the laggy animation.

How is it possible to ensure a smooth drawer close animation and concurrently load the new fragment - or is there another way to make the UI transitions look more natural?